# NLP food review classification

Tags: classification, nlp

I have a [dataset](https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon-reviews-pds/readme.html) consisting of a bunch of food reviews. I'm trying to build a model that determines if a given review talks about a food safety issue. The dataset has a lot of features, but relevant to my goal there are only two features of importance --  food reviews and their corresponding numerical ratings.

I'd love a pointer or two to figure out how to approach this problem.

As a first pass attempt, I'm thinking of pipelining all reviews into a sentiment analsyis filter and then look at the ones have keyword related to food safety (eg: "high cholesterol", "unsafe", etc)

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for "[Topic Modelling](https://cbail.github.io/SICSS_Topic_Modeling.html)"

Comment: @10xAI ok cool, would look into it. Just to confirm, is that an approach that might work given this is basically an unsupervised learning problem?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to solve your problem would be to collect the right labels for your task. Currently, you have the input i.e. text of a review and the rating which can be used to predict the sentiment of the review, but not whether it mentions safety issues. To collect the right labels, you should look at each review and assign it a binary label - 0 means food safety issues are not mentioned, 1 means they are mentioned. The feasibility of such data collection depends on the size of the dataset and the importance of your project. How big is your dataset? How much time/money are you willing to commit to that project? Once you collect the labels, you can train and evaluate a neural network based on them. If this answer helps you, feel free to ask for elaboration, I don't know what's your level of data science expertise and don't want to state the obvious.

Comment: thanks for the answer - appreciate it. Problem is, the dataset is huge - it has about 2 million entries, so I don't think a supervised learning approach would be the best idea.  Do you think something like topic modelling would work?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with topic modelling, this might be something worth trying. However, the problem that persists even with any approach in your setup is that without the labels, you won't be able to evaluate how the method you decide to develop performs on the task i.e. how well are you detecting mentions of safety issues in reviews? By extension, when you develop a second method, you won't be able to compare which method performs better.

Comment: Here's what I would do: Given the size of the dataset, I would randomly sample a fraction of reviews, for example 1000 out of the 2 millions you have. Then label manually this thousand. I don't have space here for exact calculations but labeling this should take you 4 to 16 hours depending on the length of your reviews etc. Then split the dataset into training set (700 labelled reviews), development set (200 labelled reviews) and test set (100 labelled reviews). Now you can perform supervised learning. I think it's crucial that you use a pretraining languge model such as Roberta. (1/2)

Comment: Pretrained language models are freely available in libraries such as huggingface, here's an example how to finetune a pretrained model on a custom dataset (e.g. your food reviews dataset) https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html. By using a pretrained model you don't need your labelled dataset to be as large as if you were training it from scratch. (2/3)

Comment: Once you train the model in your setting and evaluate it on the development set, take a look at the accuracy or whatever evaluation metric you choose and based on that decide if the results are satisfactory. If not, label more data and repeat the process. Now I got quite curious about your results, so feel free to DM me once you get them ;)(3/3)

Comment: thanks for the feedback! I will have a look into this.

Comment: @I have added a link to the dataset if you'd like to have a look (I wasn't previously aware it was open source)

Comment: I've stumbled upon a weird issue in the prediction step using this lib; feel free to have a look here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66520993/tensorflow-transformers-how-to-test-a-model-after-fitting-it